# How to formalize that proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Let define $\xi$ an arithmetic fonction such that : $\xi(n)=\underset{k_1+...+k_l=n} \max lcm (k_1,...k_l)$, where $k_1,...,k_l\in \mathbb{N}^{*}$.

I have to prove that $\xi(n)=\underset{p_1^{a_1}+...+p_s^{a_s}\le n}\max (p_1^{a_1}...p_s^{a_s})$, where $p_1,...,p_s$ are distinct prime numbers.

I meet difficulties to write it correctly. Here is my attempt.

Using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic I have :

$k_1=p_{1,1}^{a_{1,1}}...p_{s,1}^{a_{s,1}}, \ k_2=p_{1,2}^{a_{1,2}}...p_{s,2}^{a_{s,2}}, \ \ ..., \ \ k_l=p_{1,l}^{a_{1,l}}...p_{s,l}^{a_{s,l}}$.

Then by a strong formula $lcm(k_1,...,k_l)=\prod \limits_{i,k}p_{i,k}^{\max(a_{i,k})}$ but here I don't know how to write it well too many indexes...

Maybe I can say that $p_1$ is the first prime number which is in every $k_i$ but I'm quickly confused.

Also if we have $k_1+...+k_l=n$ then $p_1^{a_1}+...+p_s^{a_s}\le n.$

Thanks in advance !

**NB** : Apparently this function is well-known and here is an asymptotic result about it : $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{\ln(\xi(n))}{\sqrt{(n\ln(n))}}=1$.

Comment: I think it'd be simpler to define N={lcm (k)} and M={prod p^k}.  It easy to show N is a subset of M so max N <= max M.  And it's easy to show that if w in M then there exists a v in N so that w <= v.  So max M <= max N.  So max N = max M.

Comment: When notation becomes cumbersome,  create some abbreviations. Your "strong formula" as written is intelligible to me, but a computer might balk, depending on how well it can handle a human's  "You-know-what-I-mean" .... For $n\geq 2$ let $P(n)$ be the set of primes not exceeding $n.$  For $1\leq k\leq n$ let $k=\prod_{p\in P(n)}p^{a(k,p)}.$  For $\phi\ne S\subset \mathbb N^*$ with $\max S\leq n,$  and for $p\in P(n),$ let $A(p,S)=\max_{k\in S}a(k,p).$ ... Then $lcm (S)=\prod_{p\in P(n)}p^{A(p,S)}.$

Comment: I find it annoying that \gcd is a thing in MathJax but \lcm is not.